# Bootstrap Accordion Collapse Toggle Button Not Collapsing Panel

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have an MVC application and depending on if the model is for a proposer or additional driver I have a two buttons to move onto the next accordion panel. 
The button that is built when the user is a proposer works, but the one built when not a proposer does not, despite the two buttons being exactly alike.

```
 @if (Model.IsProposer)
  {
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#ContactDetails" class="btn btn-default pull-right" onclick="$('#headingOne').addClass('complete')">Continue</a>
  }
  else
  {
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#DrivingLicence" class="btn btn-default pull-right" onclick="$('#headingOne').addClass('complete')">Continue</a>
  }
```

Any ideas why the panel is not collapsing?

Comment: Is there an element with the Id "DrivingLicence" present in the DOM when the button is clicked? Also, did you try clicking it with the console open (press F12) and see if any error messages are shown?

Comment: Yeah the div exists and that one opens but the current one doesn't collapse - opening the console shows me the rendered HTML but no error messages

Comment: Your code looks right, so I'd guess you have an ID mismatch somewhere. Either a typo, or you write out a different/double accordion id depending on your model? Posting the rest of the view might help.